# Как выбрать блок <p?

Tags: jquery, php, css, javascript

Из всех блоков `<p>` нужно выбрать один или два содежащих самый большой размер текста внутри.

Интересует код на jscript, css, jquery или php и т.д.

Или просто общий принцип.

Comment: всегда радовала общая свалка, когда пхп приравнивают к js, css, jquery)))

Answer (score 5):

```
var maxlen = 0;
var maxLenLink = null;
$('p').each(function(){
  if($(this).text().length>maxlen){//и правда
    maxlen = $(this).text().length;
    maxLenLink = $(this);
  }
});
maxLenLink.css({'color':'red'});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var max = 0;  
var index = 0; 
$("p").each(function(){   
  var height = $(this).height();   
  if(height > max){      
        max = height; 
        index =  $(this).index();
  }   
});
alert("Max height:"+max+" . It's Index: "+index);
```